# Jasmine 4: Async function did not complete within 5000ms issue

Tags: asynchronous, promise, jasmine

I have an existing async function:

```
  async doJSONGetRequest(getUrl, accessToken) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      const reqHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      };

      console.info('url = ' + getUrl);
      request.get({
        url: getUrl,
        headers: reqHeaders,
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        try {
          // console.debug(`response = ${response.body}`);
          const parsed = JSON.parse(response.body);
          return resolve(parsed);
        } catch (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to test it with Jasmine(v4).
Of course, I don't want this thing to actually make an HTTP request, so I tried rigging up a spy on the 'request' package's 'get' function in the 'beforeAll' section:

```
describe('RAPIDAPIService', function() {
  beforeAll(async function() {
    spyOn(request, 'get')
      .and
      .callFake(async (parameters) => {
        if (parameters.url === 'http://localhost/api/getSomething') {
          const rsp = {};
          rsp.body = 'good stuff';
          return rsp;
        } else if (parameters.url === 'http://localhost/api/whoops') {
          return new Error('401 not found');
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });
  });


  it('doJSONGetRequest should run successfully', async () => {
    expect(api.doJSONGetRequest).toBeDefined();
    const res = await api.doJSONGetRequest('http://localhost/api/getSomething', '12345678');
    expect(data).toEqual('good stuff');
  });

  it('doJSONGetRequest should resolve errors properly', async () => {
    expect(api.doJSONGetRequest).toBeDefined();
    const res = await api.doJSONGetRequest('http://localhost/api/whoops', '12345678');
    const expectedError = new Error('401 not found');
    expect(res).toEqual(expectedError);
  });
```

Console log statements seem to indicate that I'm actually getting past / returning something from my "await" calls in the "it" tests. But the spies are actually working / detecting that the url's have been called.

(Note that I'm not including here other tests in the same file that do not make asynchronous calls and ARE working... just so you know that there's no problem accessing the actual "api" library and its functions.)

These two tests keep failing with "Error:  Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms".   And like I said, it seems like they're not returning back to the tests from their calls to the doJSONGetRequest function.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking the issue is the mocking. `request.get` seems to take two parameters and I am thinking you need to call the 2nd parameter (callback function) once you are done so the `resolve` can be called.

Try this:

```
spyOn(request, 'get')
      .and
      // add callbackFunction as 2nd argument
      .callFake((parameters, callbackFunction) => {
        if (parameters.url === 'http://localhost/api/getSomething') {
          const rsp = {};
          rsp.body = 'good stuff';
          callbackFunction(null, rsp);
        } else if (parameters.url === 'http://localhost/api/whoops') {
          callbackFunction({ error: '401 not found' }, {});
        } else {
          callbackFunction(null, null);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Yep!  That was basically the problem!   Thanks VERY much!  (I'm obviously inexperienced in dealing with callbacks.  They seem very... awkward... to me.)